# About PHP’s memory usage

Tags: php, apache

My PHP application on Windows+Apache has stopped with showing “Out of memory (allocated 422313984) (tried to allocate 45792935 bytes)”.

I can’t understand why it’s stopped because my machine has 4GB physical memory and I’ve set `memory_limit` directive for -1 in PHP.ini file. I’ve also restarted Apache.

I think 4GB is enough to allocate more than 422313984+45792935 byte memories.

Is there another setting to use memory for PHP or Apache?

I also summarize performance counter .It shows MAX memory usage was 2GB in total of machine. And the httpd process used 1.3GB.

I can’t show the code but actually the code fetches 30000 rows, 199 byte each, from DBMS and parsese into XML using `simplexml_load_string()` in a loop.

The code is normally finished if its data is small or shorten looping term like 30000 to 1000.

Another case is the first run after starting Apache will be succeeded.

I think some memory leak happen.

Actually I did echo `PHP_INT_SIZE` and PHP shows 4.　So perhaps my PHP is 32-bit version.

If memory usage problem is from this version of PHP as Álvaro G. Vicario points at bellow, can I fix it by changing for 64-bit version of PHP? And how can I get to 64-bit version of PHP for Windows? I can’t find it in http://windows.php.net

Comment: Well the message tells you that it isn't using 4GB: 422,313,984 bytes != 4GB.... check that you've updated the correct php.ini file

Comment: Are you sure about that problem present in your code? if yes means post your code.

Comment: When the `memory_limit` directive is exceeded, you get a different message: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted (tried to allocate Y bytes)`. Your message means that PHP crashed, which is a different issue.

Comment: Check the loops in the codes....

Comment: That's a heavy application. Maybe you should start optimizing its memory usage.

Comment: I add informaion .See edited.

Comment: So your app is using 2 GB of RAM? Do you have a 64-bit version of PHP?

Comment: Reading your description of what the program does, I'm fairly sure you could do it without having to have that kind of memory overhead. You might want to read this for example: http://codeinthehole.com/writing/creating-large-xml-files-with-php/

Comment: What you are probably doing is creating 30K SimpleXMLElement objects in a hash, possibly with related storage.   If you are doing something dumb like using create_function() inside a processing loop the this could easily exhaust memory.  Without example code, we can't give more specific advice

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - Do you find it a bit ridiculous using 2GB for a PHP application? If an application is that memory intensive perhaps PHP is not the technology to be using in the first place.

Comment: @EdHeal - 2GB of RAM is quite a lot for any 32-bit piece of software but it's very far from the usual requirements of web applications which can handle hundreds of simultaneous requests. If you do need such amount of memory, PHP is not for you. (And you don't normally need it—we are not rendering movies or sequencing DNA...)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - Do not quite understand your answer? Are you agreeing or disagreeing with me?

Comment: @EdHeal - I answer your question and I agree with your statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*«Out of memory»* messages (not to be confused with *«Allowed memory size exhausted»* ones) always indicate that the PHP interpreter literally ran out of memory. There's no PHP or Apache setting you can tweak—the computer is just no able to feed PHP with more RAM. Common causes include:

- Scripts that use too much memory.
- Memory leaks or bugs in the PHP interpreter.

SimpleXML is a by no means a lightweight extension. On the contrary, its easy of use and handy features come at a cost: high resource consumption. Even without seeing a single line of code, I can assure that SimpleXML is totally unsuitable to create an XML file with 30,000 items. A PHP script that uses 2GB of RAM can only take down the whole server.

Nobody likes changing a base library in the middle of a project but you'll eventually need to do so. PHP provides a pull parser called [XMLWriter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php). It's really not much harder to use and it provides two benefits:

- It's way less resource intensive, since it doesn't create the complex object that SimpleXML uses.
- You can [flush partial results](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-flush.php) to file.
- Can even [write to file directly](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-open-uri.php).

With it, I'm sure your 2 GB script can run with a few MB.

Comment: Thanks I’ll try XMLWriter.By the way the message said my app use 422,313,984bytes (422MB) and about to use more 45,792,935bytes (45MB) then stoped. I think at least 1.5GB memories are available even though 32-bit version of PHP can only use 2GB.

Comment: Still, it's too much. If you have many simultaneous requests, your server is dead.

Comment: I add information about performance counter see edited question.And now I understand what Álvaro G. Vicario said. Apache already used 1.3GB and only less than 700MB was available. By the way how do you know the information what 32-bit PHP can only use 2GB of RAM ?

Comment: @user1345414 - I don't really know. I just thought it was [a good bet](http://www.viva64.com/en/k/0036/).